# How to disable swipe navigation of flipview on touch in c# in windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp, flipview

I have developed an app in which I have more than one page in flipview.
now I want to stop the swipe navigation on touch only. i have used Isenabled property but
This will disable the content of the flipview as well, I just wanted to disable its navigation but allow the user to interact with its content because I have need to drag and drop and also zoom-in and zoom-out with its content.
please help me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this method by setting the ManipulationMode as TranslateX  and put the code below inside your FlipView:

xaml:

```
  <FlipView Width="300" Height="300" Name="MyFlipView">
        <FlipViewItem ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationDelta="FlipViewItem_ManipulationDelta">
            <Image Source="Assets/1.jpg" ></Image>
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationDelta="FlipViewItem_ManipulationDelta">
            <Image Source="Assets/2.jpg" ></Image>
        </FlipViewItem>
    </FlipView>
```

code behind:

```
        private void FlipViewItem_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta.Translation.X != 0)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable the swipe navigation of FlipView on touch without affecting the FlipViewItem content, please override the ControlTemplate and change ManipulationMode as None in ItemsPresenter and put the code below inside your FlipView:

```
<FlipView.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ItemsPresenter ManipulationMode="None"></ItemsPresenter>
    </ControlTemplate>
</FlipView.Template>
```

I have tested it and it works OK.

Comment: but sir it stops the navigation on button click also